# How to align a HTML table and description text on the same line

Tags: html, css

I have this table in html and I would wish to have this format where the description "C2B Payments" comes on the same line as the table as shown on the image, to the left on the same line and not on top of the table. However I cant figure out of a way to do it.
Any one please lead me. Thank you

```
<p class="align left"> C2B Payments</p>
<table border="0" align="center"; margin: 0 auto;">
  <thead>
    <tr>       
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Total Received</th>
      <td>Failed</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
```

CSS

```
  .alignleft {
      float: left;
       }
```

Comment: where is the image ?

Comment: why to use space for class name  - class="align left"

Comment: You have used totally wrong css like margin:0 auto without starting. Solve them first. and also use right class name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This?:
https://jsfiddle.net/d8bpy3gk/

```
    <p style="float:left; width:20%"> C2B Payments</p>
<table style="border:0; align:center; margin: 0 auto;float:left; width:80%">
  <thead>
    <tr>       
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Total Received</th>
      <th>Failed</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
     <tr>       
      <th>10/10/10</th>
      <th>$ 200,00</th>
      <th>Failed</th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add two division

- with float: left;
- with display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;

and put paragraph in left and table in right